# Integrals over ellipses/ellipsoids?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I was wondering if I want to integrate over $$4x^2+9y^2+z^2=1$$ is it enough if I say that 
$$\begin{cases}x=\frac{1}{2}r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) \\
y=\frac{1}{3}r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) \\
z=r\cos(\phi)\end{cases}$$

and recalculate the Jacobian?

Is this working?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to recalculate the Jacobian, just recall that in general if you have to integrate over an ellipsoid, let $\Phi$ be the change of coordinates (elliptic spherical coordinates) then $|\det J_\Phi|=abcr^2\sin \phi$. In your case $a=\frac{1}{2}, b=\frac{1}{3}, c=1$ so $|\det J_\Phi|=\frac{1}{6}r^2\sin \phi$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/825714)

Comment: @TheCount ok, sorry.